# Error converting varchar to bigint

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I got the error where my data type is varchar, then I want to insert value/input in `textboxt = 'smh85670s'`.

It appear to be error. As far as I know varchar can accept characters and numbers, but why does it keep throwing this error?

If I insert value '123456' the table can accept that value.

Please guide me. What data type should I use?

Comment: are you sure your data type is varchar? could you post your tables definition and also the query you are using to insert.

Comment: What error are you getting? What type is the destination table column ?

Comment: Meanwhile, take a look on this: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: G guys! cut the guy some slack. Obviously he is having a hard time explaining this in a foreign language.

Comment: The column you're inserting `smh85670s` needs to be a VARCHAR column - based on the error message, it sounds like it's a BIGINT column.

Comment: Can you share with us your `INSERT INTO` query that you are using to perform this? Perhaps it's just a matter of sticking double-quotes around your value... where a number will auto-cast to a varchar, but an unquoted string will be interpreted as garbage.

Comment: @musiw Please edit you question and clarify that the data type of the destination. It appears that the destination is BIGINT if that is correct then it is not reasonable to expect 'smh85670s' as a valid number.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Stored procedures (which have an insert query) or directly firing an insert query into DB, you must be sending all data as parameters like  say `@param1`, `@param2`,...

Your insert query will be like

```
INSERT INTO Sometable ( Amount, textbox,... )
SELECT @param1, @param2 ,...
```

Just add a cast in this query to make it work

```
INSERT INTO Sometable ( Amount, textbox,... )
SELECT @param1, CAST(@param2 as varchar),...
```

Comment: in my table i create a field noseries as varchar.when i try to insert '123' it can accept.but when i try 'smh85670s' it got error.

Comment: What's the length of varchar?

Comment: Then you must be trying to insert `smh85670s` (which is varchar) in to a column which is bigint. Either the column definition is not varchar(100) or you are inserting into wrong column

Comment: Insert Into Butiran_Dtl(RefNumber, jenisroda, SaizRoda, Flange,  
Hollow, Tindakan, skid, Catatan, status, sendby, UpdateBy, Dateupdate,nosiri) 
Values  (160405124419102, 2, 823, 8,  8, 1, 0,NULL , 0, 300988, 300988, getdate(),smh85670s) i try this query in sql,it got error.but when i remove smh the query complete successfully.

Comment: Your query should have quotes around string fields like so  `Butiran_Dtl(RefNumber, jenisroda, SaizRoda, Flange, Hollow, Tindakan, skid, Catatan, status, sendby, UpdateBy, Dateupdate,nosiri) Values (160405124419102, 2, 823, 8, 8, 1, 0,NULL , 0, 300988, 300988, getdate(),'smh85670s')`

Comment: <System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)>
    Public Shared Function AddDtl(ByVal ParentId As String, ByVal NoSiri As String, ByVal JenisGandar As String, ByVal SaizRoda As String, ByVal Flange As String, ByVal Hollow As String, ByVal Tindakan As String, ByVal Catatan As String, ByVal IsSkidded As String) As System.String   i already pass the value as string

Comment: Ah! So it looks like issue is not with `nosiri` but with `RefNumber` column. You are inserting a string into RefNumber. Try converting 160405124419102 to biginteger

Comment: i already try change refnumber data type.stil got the same error.i just dont know why..this is wasting my time.varchar is not a problem actually..i always use varchar.is it something with my DB?